# Sum a daily time series into a monthly time series with a NaN value threshold

Tags: python, sum, nan, threshold, python-xarray

I have a 3D time series data matrix from January 1st, 1979 to December 31st, 2005. The matrix is currently 9862x360x720 (daily rainfall x 0.5° latitude x 0.5° longitude). I want to sum the daily rainfall into monthly rainfall (a total of 324 months) while also setting a threshold for summing NaN values.

In other words, If there are more than 10 daily NaN values for a particular lat/lon grid cell, I want to marked the monthly summed cell as NaN. If there are less than 10 daily NaN values for the grid cell, I want to sum the remaining non-NaN daily values and use that as the monthly value.

I had success using the xarray library's "resample" function, but I couldn't figure out a way to set a threshold for NaN values. Everything I've read says to use sum or nansum functions, but I can't find a way to set a NaN threshold through either of those functions. I'm open to any method at this point (xarray or otherwise).

```
import netCDF4
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

f = netCDF4.Dataset("daily_data", 'r')

daily_dataset = xr.Dataset({'precipitation': (['time', 'lat', 'lon'],  f['precipitation'][:, :, :])},
             coords={'lat': (f['lat'][:]), 'lon': (f['lon'][:]), 'time': pd.date_range('1979-01-01', periods=9862)})

monthly_dataset = daily_dataset['precipitation'].resample('M', dim='time', how='sum', skipna=False)
```

I was able to sum the daily data to monthly with the above code, but I was not able to set a NaN threshold. The daily data is currently stored in a NetCDF file.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve]. Code from your current attempt would be helpful.

Comment: So you need a function that takes a iterable to sum up and a threshold for nans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you want:

```
NaN = float("nan") # Make a constant for NaN

def sum_nan_threshold(iterable, *, nan_threshold=10):
    if sum(x == NaN for x in iterable) >= nan_threshold: # Are there more NaNs then threshold?
        return NaN
    else:
        return sum(x for x in iterable if x != NaN) # Else sum up if not equal to NaN
```