# How to make a sum in NetCDF4 by xarray

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

I would like to make a monthly sums of my NetCDF4 file from daily values for precipitation. However, I am quite not sure what I am doing wrong. It seems that something has changed from the code in this post: [Sum a daily time series into a monthly time series with a NaN value threshold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630460/sum-a-daily-time-series-into-a-monthly-time-series-with-a-nan-value-threshold)

I didn't find anything helpful in the library documentation.

Here is my code:

```
import netCDF4
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

data = xr.open_dataset('C3S_concat_cropped.nc')
# or I can use 
data2 = Dataset("C3S_concat_cropped.nc", "r", format="NETCDF4")
print(data)
Out:
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:             (lat: 115, lon: 140, time: 15157)
Coordinates:
  * lat                 (lat) float64 -7.4 -7.5 -7.6 -7.7 ... -18.6 -18.7 -18.8
  * lon                 (lon) float64 21.1 21.2 21.3 21.4 ... 34.8 34.9 35.0
  * time                (time) datetime64[ns] 1979-01-01 ... 2020-06-30
Data variables:
    Precipitation_Flux  (time, lat, lon) float32 ...

daily_dataset = xr.Dataset({'Precipitation_Flux': (['time', 'lat', 'lon'],
data['Precipitation_Flux'][:, :, :])}, coords={'lat': (data['lat'][:]), 
'lon': (data['lon'][:]), 'time': pd.date_range('1979-01-01', periods=15157)})

monthly_dataset = daily_dataset['Precipitation_Flux'].resample(indexer='M', time="1D", 
skipna=False).sum()
```

My ValueError:

```
ValueError: the first argument to .resample must be a dictionary
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I founded that this command works for me!

```
monthly_dataset = daily_dataset['Precipitation_Flux'].resample(time ='M', 
skipna=False).sum()
```

However, the documentation of xarray.Dataset.resample can be quite confusing, as the first argument of the function - indexer is not typically written! So be aware of that! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.groupby` instead of `.resample`.

This should work:

```
monthly_dataset =daily_dataset['Precipitation_Flux'].groupby('time.month').sum('time')
```

You first group the data by months and then you have to take the sum along the time axis.

Comment: This will actually create dataset with 12 records (months) and very high precipitation volumes (around 17 000 mm in rainy season). However, at least something is working :-) Now think about how to make it for every year separately. Btw... Why resample is not working anymore for that? :-)